# What is the difference between using <<access>> and <<import>> when implementing a package diagram?

Tags: import, uml, package, diagram

We are covering UML diagrams in one of my university modules, and we briefly covered package diagrams. I understand that in a package diagram, when there is a connection (or arrow) between two packages and it is labelled with import, it means that the contents of the target package are added to the source's public namespace, while access adds it to the private namespace and cannot be re-exported when a third package imports the original source package. My question is how would you actually implement the import and access in code? For example with Java you have;

import Java.swing.*;

As far as I know there is no access key-word, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Importing a package is equivalent to importing it's all public elements. So, the visibility of import can be thought of the visibility of the elements (imported elements). 
Here is an example in C# depicting the difference between "access" and "import". It is easy to map the code to Java:

```
namespace Logger
{
  public class FileLogger
  {
     public void LogTimeToFile(string fileName, string time)
     {
       //....
     }
  }
}

namespace ServerTime
{
  public class TimeProvider
  {
     public string GetTime()
     {
       //....
     }
  }
}

namespace ServerTimeLog
{
  public class Logger
  {
    private Logger.FileLogger logger; // Logger is access but not imported
    public  ServerTime.TimeProvider timeProvider; // ServerTime is imported

    public void LogCurrentTime()
    {
       logger.LogTimeToFile("c:\\log.txt", timeProvider.GetTime());
    }
  }
}

namespace TaskLog
{
  ServerTimeLog.Logger serverTimeLogger;

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
      // serverTimeLogger.logger ----> Inaccessible because it was accessed not imported
      // serverTimeLogger.timeProvider ----> Accessible because it was imported
  }
}
```

Comment: Concrete answer, and extends to multiple languages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't, necessarily.

Questions about relating UML constructs to source constructs in a particular language are in general meaningless. Java isn't the world's only programming language, nor is UML much good at documenting source code.

UML deals with abstracts, while source code is an implementation and therefore concrete. To bridge the gap, you need an adaptation ("profile") of UML which specifies how each source construct is represented, and there are essentially no standardized profiles for any of the common languages.

Instead, the different tool vendors choose how to represent the various source constructs for the languages where they support forward and/or reverse engineering. In tool X, the access and import stereotypes may or may not have any meaning with regard to language Y; a Java package might well be represented by a UML class.

So the question can really only be answered in the context of a specific tool and a specific language.

Answer (score 1):

According to Visual Paradigm Uml [help](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/Package.html), they are very close, only " The keyword <<import>> is shown near the dashed arrow if the visibility is public; otherwise, the keyword <<access>> is shown to indicate private visibility."

Comment: actually, that is quite a difference: access to internals vs accessing the public interface changes a lot in terms of coupling. Thanks for that reference :)